# Trying to import zip file into jupyter notebook and syntax error

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am working on a macbook, python 3.8, and I am having a bad time when it comes to importing files in juptyer notebook. I know I could do it manually, but I want to learn with coding (i feel like it should not be this hard). I am also quite new to python I would say.

So this is the code I am using:

```
import os
import 'C:/Users/bob/Downloads/filename.zip'
```

the error I keep getting is

```
import 'C:/Users/bob/Downloads/filename.zip'
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

-the carrot is pointing at the ' , and I have tried without quotations and then the carrot points at the colon

the file path is right, the filename is right, and I really do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by import a zip file?  Do you want to a list of the contents of the zip file?

Comment: okay I see. as you can tell I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import files with import comand, that is reserved for modules.

You should read this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817648/opening-folders-in-zip-files-python) and how to open files in python

Comment: thank you, I saw that post earlier, but i looked at it again and it helped!